# How to disable auto create customer profile after edit order?

Tags: 7, commerce

When I edit order (at url admin/commerce/orders/1/edit) and save order, a new custom profile will be created. I don't want that. How can I disable that?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the inline customer profile form has the country selected, which is all that's required for a field value to be present. I believe we should add a fix to Drupal Commerce core to prevent this, but I don't know off the top of my head if there's already an issue in the queue for it. Feel free to search at https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/commerce and file an issue if you don't see it already. Thanks!

Comment: I was created issue at [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2853428).